# How to get the line number of each line across multiple files in Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark

I have an S3 bucket with multiple JSONL files. Every line within each file is a JSON string.

Currently, I read the files as follows:

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.read().option("recursiveFileLookup", "true").json(path);
```

This gives me a dataset with all the fields of the JSON objects.

For every row, I need its corresponding line number within the source file.

Eg:

```
File1.jsonl:
-------------
{"key1": "a"}
{"key1": "b"}
{"key1": "c"}

File2.jsonl:
-------------
{"key1": "x"}
{"key1": "y"}
{"key1": "z"}
```

I need the dataset to be like:

Dataset

| key1 | file_name | line_num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | file1 | 1 |
| b | file1 | 2 |
| c | file1 | 3 |
| x | file2 | 1 |
| y | file2 | 2 |
| z | file2 | 3 |

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`monotonically_increasing_id()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id.html) inbuilt function for this case.

```
df.withColumn("mid",monotonically_increasing_id()))
```

---

If this mid doesn't give the expected results then use this `mid` column as **orderby** column to generate `row_number()` on the dataframe.

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df1 = df1.withColumn("mid", monotonically_increasing_id())
windowSpec = W.orderBy("mid")
df1 = df1.withColumn("line_num", row_number().over(windowSpec)).show()
```